# 'Will be' vs 'going to be' with future facts

Tags: future-tense, will-vs-going-to

I know we can use '*will be*' to talk about future facts, eg.

> l will be 34 tomorrow.

But, can we use '*going to be*' instead of '*will be*', at least in informal situations?

> l'm going to be 34 tomorrow.

Comment: Yes, you can. There's nothing wrong your sentence.

Comment: @Nair That means they are totally synonymous?

Comment: The `going to be` construction is informal, `will` can be used in both formal and informal situations.

Comment: @semperos  Yea. Good explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although **will** and **going to** are different in some ways, *in casual speech and writing*, will and going to are often interchanged.

When we want to talk about *future facts* or things we believe to be true about the future, we use **will**.